# Monte Carlo Sampling is performing better then Bayesian Optimization

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

So I am testing the [Bayesian optimization library](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization) for determining where to sample next by quering a test function such as 2d Rosenbrock to better reconstruct that function using Gaussian Process regression. In other words I want to perform selective sampling of the function to reconstruct that function using Gaussian Process regression (GP) in least amount of selective sampling.

So in the literature Bayesian optimization is considered a best way to learn a function in fewer steps efficiently. So lets say I want to sample at 100 locations and then construct the estimation of Rosenbrock function using GP, performing pure random or monte carlo sampling gives better results then performing Bayesian optimization!

So I want to ask why is Bayesian optimization considered useful then?

---

Additional notes:

The reproducible code would be very huge beyond the scope of SE guidlines.
Based on the answer the additional information is following:

- the a priori information is initially constructed by performing random sampling or MC sampling of the function and fitting the GP - which automatically tunes the hyperparameters in the Sklearn library.
- The kernel that is fitted is Matern which is widely used for such cases.
- In general if I am doing sampling such as 100 samples, then in case of pure MC sampling i am taking all 100 samples randomly and then fitting the GP and comparing with the Rosenbrok function to see the error and for Bayesian i am taking 50 samples randomly initially - fitting the GP to form the prior - 50 using Bayesian optimization and then re-fitting the GP and comparing with the Rosenbrok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have given no reproducible code for us to investigate what is leading you to the results you have found. You also state that you want to reconstruct the function which neither random sampling nor Monte Carlo will perform.

Bayesian active sampling and Gaussian processes more generally perform well in regression when the priors over function spaces encoded in the kernel place sufficient probability mass over the function which you are hoping to infer. Mismatches in prior information can indeed hinder performance. If I was to diagnose your results I would start there and ask is the kernel appropriate and what is happening to the hyper parameters during optimisation.

Bayesian optimisation however is used to find global maxima or minima. It is generally speaking used when the optimisation surface is assumed multimodal and it is desirable to both explore the space and exploit modes under a limited budget. Once again this is only useful when the kernel uses in BO incorporates some a priori knowledge of the space such as smoothness.

Comment: I have included additional details incase you would want to elaborate your answer.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Thanks for the additional information. I'm still not sure why you are doing BO as I believe you are looking to do active sampling without a bias towards optimisation (purely exploration with no exploitation). If you wanted to do a similar comparison that was more appropriate for BO, I would compare the minima (or maxima depending on the optimisation goal) of the random selection versus BO. Also, I would suggest confirming that the BO kernel and the fitted kernel are the same.

Comment: Equally, if it is that you simply want to do active sampling to minimize the residual error, I can give you some alternative acquisition functions which will not endeavor to optimize the space.

Happy to help if you are still having difficulties.

Comment: Yes correct. I am using EI as acquisition function. Please do suggest alternatives.

Comment: So if you want to simply explore the space then you could do something similar in nature to EI by setting the acquisition function to just the standard deviation of the GP. In essence acquire points based on where your GP has greatest uncertainty. What you will be doing is sampling points away from one another like draws from a determinental point process (DPP). If you work through the math you'll notice this process does not consider the y-values of the observations other than for optimizing the kernel. Hope it works better for you, let us know!